# How to change app theme (Light/Dark) in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with up to 10 screens and in the settings screen, I have a toggle to switch between dark/light mode. I want to change the complete app theme on that toggle.

Currently, the app theme change when I change the theme in iOS default settings. But I want the same behavior to happen for my app only.

What I figure out till now is to set a theme variable in the user default and use this code conditional on each view controller

```
    view.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = // .dark // .light
```

I don't want to use any third party library.

Comment: Overriding the window’s interface style should override for all its subviews.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` read the preference from shared defaults and do something like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = preference == "dark" ? .dark : .light
```

In your Settings view controller do the same when the user changes the preference.

Setting the override on your window should take care of all view controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's working great in my setting screen and changing the app theme as expected. But when i close the app and reopen it in my didfinish func its not changing them. it uses the default ios theme. What should I do?

Comment: It works when I put the theme condition in my scene delegate file. However, your answer helps me a lot thank you so much.

Comment: @HamasHassan where did you put it in scene delegate?

Comment: @dejavu89 you can refer to the complete code here.

https://github.com/Hamashassan/Insides.io/blob/master/Insides/SceneDelegate.swift

Comment: When I relaunch app, Its running on .light mode, instead of dark mode. Any suggestion please ? @csmith

Comment: "'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes"

Answer (score 4):

Here's how i have done the same approach on similar kind of use case. I have created an extension for `AppDelegate` like below:

```
extension AppDelegate {
    func overrideApplicationThemeStyle() {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            ....
            // Retrieve your NSUserDefaults value here
            ....
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = yourUserDefaultsValue ? .dark : .light
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

And, my theme change is device specific. So, i have created one boolean instance in `NSUserDefaults` to keep the toggle changes. And, whenever the toggle changes i will call the method:

```
@IBAction func changeApplicationTheme() {
    ....
    // Your code to store the changes in NSUserDefaults
    ....
    AppDelegate.shared.overrideApplicationStyle()
}
```

And, more importantly this theme has been introduced from iOS 13 onwards the best place to call it from `func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)` whenever app launches and would like to apply the user selected theme.

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    AppDelegate.shared.overrideApplicationStyle()
}
```

Comment: `UIApplication keyWindow` was deprecated in iOS 13.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way of doing this with just few lines of code.

1. Save theme in User Defaults

```
@AppStorage("theme") var theme: String = ""
```

2. Change `preferredColorScheme` at root of the project based on user defaults

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            // HERE
            .preferredColorScheme(theme == "" ? .none : theme == "dark" ? .dark : .light)
    }
}
```

Done.

---

Example:

```
@main
struct YourAppNameApp: App {
    @AppStorage("theme") var theme: String = ""
    
    var body: some Scene {
        ContentView()
            .preferredColorScheme(theme == "" ? .none : theme == "dark" ? .dark : .light)
    }
}
```

Note: in this approach you can only choose between 3 options: **System theme**, **Light mode** and **Dark mode**.